# returning cell locations from a filter function result

Tags: excel, multidimensional-array, excel-formula

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get the cell positions of the results of my FILTER function formula.  I'm currently using Excel 2021 Desktop version.

My data is in a table and, but  my formula obviously isn't.  Here is the formula:

```
=FILTER(Table1[Start],(Table1[W/Prev]="Yes")*(Table1[Day]=B2),"")
```

This returns the values in the "Start" column correctly.

What I want to do is return the cell addresses of these results.

Thanks in advance....

Ive tried to use CELL"address"

MATCH only returns the first value (of course)

My problem is i don't know a function for cell reference that works on the spilled data.

Comment: `What I want to do is return the cell addresses of these results.` Why?  If it is to use it later there are better ways beside returning a cell address to get another value.

Comment: `=FILTER(ROW(Table1[Start]),(Table1[W/Prev]="Yes")*(Table1[Day]=B2),"")` ?

Comment: To get `Cell Address` you can try this as well : `=FILTER(ADDRESS(ROW(Table1[Start]),Column_No_Start)),(Table1[W/Prev]="Yes")*(Table1[Day]=B2),"")` Where enter the column index in `Column_No_Start`